# Java XPath rules in Sonarqube 5.2

Tags: java, xpath, sonarqube

I've got the Java plugin (3.7.1) and the XML plugin (1.3) installed, and I'm trying to add Xpath rules to identify things in Java. I've copy/pasted source files where I expect the rule to fire into the SSLR toolkit, and my Xpath expression is firing just fine. I found the XPath rule template in Sonar (had to install the XML plugin to get it - it's not included in the Java plugin), and put my xpath in there. I've got it matching files of type *, and it seems like maybe that rule, even though it's in the XML plugin, might support java because the template text specifically talks about matching AST nodes. However, my rule is not firing. I've made another rule to fire on XML files, and that's  working.

I've activated both rules in the Sonar Way, which is applied to the project in question, and the rules are both set to Blocker (for now- just to make some noise). But only the one that matches actual XML files is working.

What step am I missing? The documentation is a little out of date on this.

Answer (score 1):

You had to install the XML plugin to get an XPath rule because the Java plugin no longer supports writing rules in XPath. That's why the documentation is out of date; that way of writing rules has been removed.

The XPath template you have will only work against XML files. That's why you're not getting any issues.

Instead, you'll need to implement your rules *for* Java [*in* Java](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Writing+Custom+Rules+using+Java).

Comment: I knew it had been removed when they moved from PMD to SSLR, but I thought it came back.

That seems like a whole lot of ceremony for something so simple.

Comment: The reason XPath support was removed was that in the end it was unreliable. The 'path' through the AST relied on the shape of the AST, which could change from version to version causing your XPath rules to fail silently.

Comment: @Colselaw As maintainer of java plugin let me precise things : this has nothing to do with PMD. SSLR used to support Xpath rules. We drop this feature when moving to an AST with a dedicated type for each node leading to provide a more reliable API (with compile time failure) for custome rules as pointed out by Ann.